# Как сделать парсер конекта?

Tags: html, php, парсер, css

Как научиться сделать парсер конекта в формате xml? Скажем с сайта анекдотов.

Comment: Примерный код интересует. И как происходит сам процесс в двух словах (от написания до получения). Я учу PHP

Comment: Нужно распарсить НТМЛ и выбрать контент и перегнать файл в XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно не изобретать велосипед [XML_PARSER](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php),
Можно изобрести [Регулярки 1](http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/regexp_1)[,2](http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/regexp_2)
Принцип простой в обоих случаях: ищем тэги, которые нам нужны. Скажем, <anektext> и <anekdate>
В первом случае обращаемся к нему как к свойству объекта:

```
$objectAnek[100500]->anekText;
```

Во втором - регулякой:

```
preg_match("/<anekText>(.*?)<\/anekText>/g",$pageText,$matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос в другом - задача прочитать ХМЛку, или распарсить НТМЛ и выбрать контент?

Второе - на порядок интереснее)

Пример обработчика (перегоняет ХМЛ в структуру вложенных РНР массивов (лучше сразу глянуть на результат через print_r):

```
function xml2array($contents, $get_attributes=1, $priority = 'attribute') { 
if(!$contents) return array();

if(!function_exists('xml_parser_create')) { 
    //print "'xml_parser_create()' function not found!"; 
    return array(); 
}

//Get the XML parser of PHP - PHP must have this module for the parser to work 
$parser = xml_parser_create(''); 
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); # http://minutillo.com/steve/weblog/2004/6/17/php-xml-and-character-encodings-a-tale-of-sadness-rage-and-data-loss 
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0); 
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1); 
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, trim($contents), $xml_values); 
xml_parser_free($parser);

if(!$xml_values) return;//Hmm...

//Initializations 
$xml_array = array(); 
$parents = array(); 
$opened_tags = array(); 
$arr = array();

$current = &$xml_array; //Refference

//Go through the tags. 
$repeated_tag_index = array();//Multiple tags with same name will be turned into an array 
foreach($xml_values as $data) { 
    unset($attributes,$value);//Remove existing values, or there will be trouble

    //This command will extract these variables into the foreach scope 
    // tag(string), type(string), level(int), attributes(array). 
    extract($data);//We could use the array by itself, but this cooler.

    $result = array(); 
    $attributes_data = array();

    if(isset($value)) { 
        if($priority == 'tag') $result = $value; 
        else $result['value'] = $value; //Put the value in a assoc array if we are in the 'Attribute' mode 
    }

    //Set the attributes too. 
    if(isset($attributes) and $get_attributes) { 
        foreach($attributes as $attr => $val) { 
            if($priority == 'tag') $attributes_data[$attr] = $val; 
            else $result['attr'][$attr] = $val; //Set all the attributes in a array called 'attr' 
        } 
    }

    //See tag status and do the needed. 
    if($type == "open") {//The starting of the tag '<tag>' 
        $parent[$level-1] = &$current; 
        if(!is_array($current) or (!in_array($tag, array_keys($current)))) { //Insert New tag 
            $current[$tag] = $result; 
            if($attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data; 
            $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1;

            $current = &$current[$tag];

        } else { //There was another element with the same tag name

            if(isset($current[$tag][0])) {//If there is a 0th element it is already an array 
                $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result; 
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; 
            } else {//This section will make the value an array if multiple tags with the same name appear together 
                $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result);//This will combine the existing item and the new item together to make an array 
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 2;

                if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well 
                    $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr']; 
                    unset($current[$tag.'_attr']); 
                }

            } 
            $last_item_index = $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]-1; 
            $current = &$current[$tag][$last_item_index]; 
        }

    } elseif($type == "complete") { //Tags that ends in 1 line '<tag />' 
        //See if the key is already taken. 
        if(!isset($current[$tag])) { //New Key 
            $current[$tag] = $result; 
            $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1; 
            if($priority == 'tag' and $attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data;

        } else { //If taken, put all things inside a list(array) 
            if(isset($current[$tag][0]) and is_array($current[$tag])) {//If it is already an array...

                // ...push the new element into that array. 
                $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result;

                if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes and $attributes_data) { 
                    $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data; 
                } 
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++;

            } else { //If it is not an array... 
                $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result); //...Make it an array using using the existing value and the new value 
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1; 
                if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes) { 
                    if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well

                        $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr']; 
                        unset($current[$tag.'_attr']); 
                    }

                    if($attributes_data) { 
                        $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data; 
                    } 
                } 
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; //0 and 1 index is already taken 
            } 
        }

    } elseif($type == 'close') { //End of tag '</tag>' 
        $current = &$parent[$level-1]; 
    } 
}

return($xml_array);
```

}

Comment: <s>m-m-mmonsterkillkillkill...</s>

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите в сторону simplexml